# Selecting Angular material drop down option by reading data using excel sheet with Apache POI in Selenium webdriver and Data driven testing

Tags: excel, selenium, apache-poi, angular-material, testng-dataprovider

how to select Angular material drop down list option from excel sheet data/value/parameter with selenium webdriver Data driven concept and Using APACHE POI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using extension in chrome called CSS and Xpath checker , it is possible to get xpath of elements for any dropdown list , text fields etc

Example suppose we have Dropdown list called Gender and the list contains 3 options called Male , Female and Others

so the WebDriver code will be as follows

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[.='Gender']")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='mat-option-text' and contains(text(),'Male')]")).click();

or

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='mat-option-text' and contains(text(),'Female')]")).click();

or

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='mat-option-text' and contains(text(),'Others')]")).click();